# preferred way to repeatedly access core data entities

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, dry

Basically, I'm getting tired of writing `NSFetchRequest` and `NSEntityDescription` and `NSSortDescriptor` and sometimes `NSPredicate` and all that just to create/access a Core Data Entity.

I'm thinking that I'll make a Category on the Entity (as that could be used everywhere) but I wanted to check with y'all.

How do you do it all elegantly and DRY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem until I found Magical Record. It's just great to fetch entities but also removes the mess to setup CoreData.

You can find it here: https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord

Comment: Goodness gracious, that looks awesome.  Reminds me of my RoR days.  I'm going to transfer everything to it but first I gotta get this job done pronto.  Thanks!

Comment: I thought exactly the same as I found it. ;-) I use it together with RestKit so everything is perfect.